# Interview Question - Binary Search Tree

Tags: c#, .net

A friend was recently interviewed for a position at a tech company and was given 4 programming tasks.

One of the tasks was to implement a Binary Search Tree class using a Linked List implementation with search, add and remove methods that could be accessed in a thread-safe manner. He had Visual Studio 2010 but no internet connection and around 30mins.

I'd like to see people here attempt a solution without an internet connection in 30mins in C# (impossible to police I know but I trust you to be honest...)

Comment: This should probably be made a community wiki.

Comment: I feel the term "immutable" comming up here. I like to link to one of Eric Lippert's blogposts, but I have not internet connection :-P

Comment: 30 minutes? C#? no internet? Easy game, I've done that already if I correctly recall, once you know enough C# basics the rest is easy as hell and pretty straight forward... 

if it was in C then okay, I'd have asked for 1 hour instead (especially for typos and unexpected behaviors -seg faults-), but C#... easy beasy

my 2 cents

Comment: Maybe better for programmers.stackexchange.com?

Comment: You know, they didn't necessarily expect for your friend to *complete* the task in that time: getting an indication of how something is approached is often more valuable than the solution itself.

Comment: This is actually one of those `aha` questions. Some people will be familiar with the implementation of a BST, some won't. That tells you nothing about how good a fit they are for the job. If the question **defined** a BST, then gave the candidate more time to implement it, that would be a better test.

Comment: I don't think the question is very well defined. The English of the question has two meanings. Is it 'with search, add an dremove methods' refers to the LL (i.e. your friend has a LL implementation that includes search/add/remove), or does it refer to the BST class (i.e. your friend has to implement search/add/remove).

Also, I'm sorry, but I don't see how the LL can be used here, unless your friend is prohibited from using the 'new' operator (the facto using LL just as new). If 'new' is permitted, I'm not familiar with any implementation that requires a LL.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a *question* here.

Comment: 4 upvotes, 6 favourites and.....closed! I love this place sometimes.

Comment: I'm actually building my own threadsafe BST, already spent more than 30 minutes :P

Answer (score 0):

Why? Traversing the LL would be ridiculously slow, right? Sounds like a dumb question.

(Edit:) Do you mean that you have to store your BST in a Linked List?  Or that it has to support an interface like a linked list?  I was assuming the former.

Comment: it's a BST so he could add child pointers to each element

Comment: I don't think the question is that stupid. How you choose to use the linked list is up to you. At least as far as I can tell from the question. But everyone can make a BST I guess it is how you choose to do it with the requirements given that is interesting.

Comment: It's not a stupid question.  The point is to see whether the candidate actually has any knowledge of computer science, or is just a dumb code monkey.

Comment: It sounds like they're just trying to feel out basic knowledge of data structures and the like.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question. You have to implement a BST and you can only use a LL, right? I was picturing a heap stored in a linked list....

Comment: @bo1024 I think the question stated "a binary search tree using a linked list implementation" but he can't remember exactly...I assume it meant storing the BST in a linked list.

Comment: I could be missing something, but I can't think of how that could be done efficiently.... Anyone? Maybe it was meant the other way.